# Absolute value of complex fraction

Tags: complex-numbers

Can someone tell me if this is correct... if not, what would be the correct absolute value of the imaginary number below ?

Where $i$ is the imaginary number, and $\lambda$ is some constant, I have this equation. 
$$|\frac{g^{t}}{g^{t-1}}|=|\frac{1}{1-2i\lambda sin(\Delta x)}|$$
Since this is in the real number field, these have recipricals. So, does that mean :

$$|\frac{g^{t-1}}{g^{t}}|=|1-2i\lambda sin(\Delta x)|=\sqrt{1+4\lambda^2}\\
|\frac{g^t}{g^{t-1}}|=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+4\lambda^2}}$$

Or is $|\frac{g^{t}}{g^{t-1}}|*|\frac{g^{t-1}}{g^{t}}|\neq1$?

Answer (score 2):

For all complex numbers  $z_1, z_2$ we have that
$$|z_1 z_2|=|z_1||z_2|$$
Or equivalently
$$\bigg|\frac{z_1}{z_2}\bigg| =\frac{|z_1|}{|z_2|}$$
So what you have written is true.
But if the value of $\Delta x$ is also complex then you have incorrectly implied that $|\sin{(\Delta x)}|=1$ because it is possible for $\sin{(\Delta x)}$ to take any complex value for complex arguments.